# Eigenvalues of laplacian on a manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry

I was reading from the book of T. Aubin  [Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-13006-3) some basic aspects about the laplacian defined on a manifold. Concretely, regarding its eigenvalues I have seen the next proof of the fact that all of them are nonnegative.
[image]

I know this proof in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but here it is not quite clear for me the meaning $\nabla^v f$ and $\nabla_vf$ and why the product has to be positive. Are they related with the metric that we have on $g$? To better understand, if we take for example $M=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ (flat torus), how are they defined?

Comment: It's a notation I have not seen before. It should read the same as $\langle \nabla f, \nabla f\rangle$, meaning the inner product of the gradient of $f$ with itself. I can take a guess that the one with a raised $v$ is the gradient and the one with a lowered $v$ is the differential, so that their Euclidean dot product in coordinates is the same as the inner product of the gradient with itself.

Comment: Nitpicking: it is not $v$, but instead $\nu$. It's common to use greek letters as dummy indices when applying Einstein's convention. This way, $\nabla^\nu f$ is the $\nu$-component of $\nabla f$, that is, $\nabla f = (\nabla^\nu f)\partial_\nu$, so that $\nabla^\nu f = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu f$ and so $\nabla^\nu f \nabla_\nu f = g(\nabla f,\nabla f) \geq 0$.